# UIWebView playing video in landscape, and corrupted ui when video is finished

Tags: video, webview, orientation, landscape, portrait

I'm trying to fix this for a long time now, i've searched and tried every possible thing, but i still can't get it done.

My view hierarchy is this

UITabBarController

-----UINavigationController + (UIWebView subview loaded with youtube video)

-----UINavigationController

The entire app is portrait but i want to be able to see only the video in landscape.
(the viewcontroller that holds the webview should stay portrait at all times).

I've enabled landscape left & landscape right & portrait device orientations in the target properties. 
I've subclassed the UITabBar so it will ask the top view controller for orientation changes.
I've implemented SupportedInterfaceOrientation and ShouldAutorotate.

Everything thing is working as expected, you press the "play" button in the web view and it goes fullscreen, the video is able to rotate...
Where the problem begins? when you press "Done" on the fullscreen video, if the video
was in landscape mode, the view that holds the webview and it's tabbar stays in landscape.
It should stay in portrait!

I've tried to set the StatusBarOrientation when returning 0 on the supported interface orientations.
I've tried to play with transform

But i couldn't get this simple task done. Why o Why is it so complicated to force 
a re-layout in a certain orientation?

I'm clueless & hopeless

Please HELP!
thanks

I'm talking about IOS 6 rotation methods not IOS5;

Comment: @Patz- Do you found any solution?